# Print contents of array with even spacing

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that takes user input and prints that many palindromic primes (10 per line only and should be evenly spaced). I was printing the values directly and it was working fine, but the numbers are not evenly spaced. So I decided to store them into an array in hopes that they would print out evenly spaced. But now no values are printing. Can someone please point out where I made a mistake? Here is part of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Print how many values? ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        int[] palPrimes = new int[input];
        int count = 1, val = 2;

        while(count <= input)
        {
            if(isPrime(val) && isPalindrome(val))
            {
                palPrimes[count-1] = val;
            }
            val++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < palPrimes.length; i++)
        {
            if(i % 10 == 0)
                System.out.println();
            System.out.print(palPrimes[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment `count` when you add a `val` or your loop never terminates.

```
if (isPrime(val) && isPalindrome(val)) 
{
    palPrimes[count - 1] = val;
}
val++;
```

Should be something like

```
if (isPrime(val) && isPalindrome(val)) 
{
    palPrimes[count - 1] = val;
    count++;
}
val++;
```

Finally, for even spacing of the numbers, I suggest you use [formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html). Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < palPrimes.length; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("% 5d", palPrimes[i]);
}
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments by [@m3ssym4rv1n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895601/m3ssym4rv1n), a tab or two

```
System.out.print(palPrimes[i] + "\t");
```

The first option (`printf`) will align right; the later (`\t`) aligns left.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was a silly error haha
But it still prints unevenly :/

Comment: Another option for formatting is to just add a \t or two.  System.out.print(palPrimes[i] + " \t");

Answer (score 0):

Increment count as `count++` for while loop. If you want to print evenly then use :

```
System.out.printf("%-5d", palPrimes[i]);
```

> Here "-5d" align left with 5 space for all digit